# Old user name in git – despite successful change of global git config – how to change it?

Tags: git, git-config

I changed (globally) my git user name and email. When I check it with git config --list, I get a new name. But over the command line, before computer name and path, I see the old user name.

I had tried a lot of solutions that I found here, but none of it worked. Maybe because I am an absolute begginer and I barely know what I am doing... I tried eg. some actions with Windows credentials (edited it, then removed, no effect) and credential.helper.

Could somebody help me in a proper checking what is exactly wrong and repairing it, step by step?

Comment: I don't entirely know what you mean by "over the command line", but perhaps you have set up your shell prompt to print something, and perhaps this setup is wrong now.

Comment: I see the old name in Git Bash, above the place where i type commands, it is sth like that: OldUserName@ComputerName ~/path

Comment: Bash doesn't use your Git configuration, unless you program it to. That particular position is normally reserved for your *login name* on your computer, which is entirely separate from your *Git* name. (Your `PS1` string is probably set to `[%u@%h] %p\n`, or similar.)

Comment: I remember that I set up this name during Git installation. I reinstalled Git, but the second time I did not get an option of setting any name or password. And could you explain what you said in parenthesis? I do not understand what is going on with this PS1 and all.

Comment: Bash prints a command prompt based on what you set in bash's `PS1` variable. This has literally nothing at all to do with Git. Bash has access to several internal variables: your login name (for computers with more than one user; for a computer with a single user, it's just the single user's name); your host name; your current working directory; and many others. (I mis-remembered the escape character here, it's a backslash, not a percent sign.)